# Return TinyMCE colours in RGB instead of Hex?

Tags: tinymce

I need to get HTML from TinyMCE, which I have done with the `getText()` function. However, it is returning the colours as hex values, instead of RGB, and I need RGB, not hex. Is there any way to force TinyMCE to return colours in RGB format? My setup is as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: '.mainTextInput',
   plugins: 'autosave a11ychecker advcode casechange formatpainter linkchecker autolink lists checklist media mediaembed pageembed permanentpen powerpaste table advtable tinycomments tinymcespellchecker',
   toolbar: 'fontselect restoredraft a11ycheck addcomment showcomments casechange checklist code formatpainter pageembed permanentpen table',
   toolbar_mode: 'floating',
   autosave_interval: '1s',
   height: '350',
   content_style: 
   "body { font-family: 'Poppins'}",
    tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
    tinycomments_author: 'Author name',
    force_hex_style_colors: false
});
```

In HTML:

```
<div class="mainTextInput">
```

And I am getting text like this:

```
getTextButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   getText();
});
```

I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.